# Natural Shiv Ling consecration

Tags: shiva-lingam

We have found a natural Shiv Ling in a forest that we would like to consecrate and bless to Lord Shiva.

What are suggested mantras, operations and related to do it?
Water, Milk would be sufficient ?

I was thinking about to recite Shiv Sahasranama. Any suggestions on what we can do more?

Comment: Water, Milk with Mantras are called Upacharas (Services). That is not concentration. You need Purohits who serve in Temples and know how to concentrate. Or you need Yogis who can embed their own energy as concentration. That is why consecrated items gets passed on from generations.